# Bluetooth ImportError: cannot import name 'Bluetooth' from 'bluetool'

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, importerror

I've installed bluetool package in python 3.7 using "pip3 install bluetool". When I try to use it, it gives me the following error:

```
root@ccimx6ulsbc:~# python3
Python 3.7.7 (default, Jul 10 2020, 10:52:33) 
[GCC 9.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bluetool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bluetool/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bluetool import Bluetooth
ImportError: cannot import name 'Bluetooth' from 'bluetool' (/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bluetool/__init__.py)
```

but it gives me no issue when I use it from the following location:
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bluetool

I also tried appending the path to the system path:
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bluetool") but the error doesn't resolve

Comment: It's a known issue: https://github.com/emlid/bluetool/issues/10

Comment: The package has a reference bug. If used as a package the import references itself.

Comment: Is there any fix to this bug?